# Visual studio 2012 - measuring speed of few instructions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In my code I have few instructions that are connecting to my database. I would like to know how fast are they executing. I know that I can write some kind of a timer, but pasting this code into few places and then removing it after measurement, will surely leave some mess.

I want to know if maybe VS2012 has any tool to help me with that? Or is there any addon maybe?

Comment: Depending on the version of VS, there are profiling tools.  At least for VS 2010, you can download the standalone command line profiling tools for free as well.  Maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182401.aspxwill help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick one-off use of the Stopwatch class can give you insight.

Do beware that such a test isn't actually that useful.  It will repeat *very* poorly, dbase connection times heavily depend on network traffic overhead and dbase server usage.  And worst of all, there just isn't anything you can do about it in your code.  Spending time on profiling code that you cannot improve is not a very productive use of your time.

You might actually want to leave that code in place so that the user has some idea why the program is performing poorly.  Whether *that* is useful is hard to tell.